# Use javascript to get the directory of a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am using an input of type=file and I am trying to figure out how to extract the file location from it. I am using this code:

```
file = $("#uploadFiles").attr("files")[0];
var fileName = file.fileName;
var formData = 'uploadFile=' + fileName;
```

and when i alert formData, it says "uploadFile=temp.jpg"

What I want is the alerted message to be something like:

> "uploadFile=C:\user\doug\documents\pictures\temp.jpg"

But I don't know the attribute of the file object to put in for file.fileName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can only rely on the filename being accessible - used mainly as a preliminary extension checking (e.g. `(jpe?g|png|gif)$`) on the client side (which only serves to benefit the user, to stop them from uploading a 5mb file that will be not validate on the server anyway).

You can access whatever the browser will give you with...

#### jQuery

```
$('file[type=input]').val();
```

#### JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('file-input').value;
```

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, this is completely impossible in modern browsers.

Comment: unless you're working on a local script, in which case it is possible on some browsers (at least Firefox) to request additional permissions, such as File IO.